# Solving $\frac{\cos(2x)^2}{\sin(2x)^2} = 1 +\frac{3}{\cos(2x)}$ for $x$

Tags: trigonometry

Professor said it should be easy....

> How can one find $x$ here?
>
> $$\frac{\cos(2x)^2}{\sin(2x)^2} = 1 +\frac{3}{\cos(2x)}$$

I've already tried my textbooks and Mathematica. Could it just be undefined?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Next time write your question in mathjax. It's easier for us to see it and to copy and past it if needed.

Comment: If you use the double-angle formulas for $\cos(2x)$ and $\sin(2x)$, as well as $(\sin x)^2 = 1-(\cos x)^2$, then you can turn the equation into a polynomial equation in $\cos x$. That polynomial is irreducible of degree $4$, so the solutions won't be particularly nice.

Comment: @Greg Martin I see, before I try that though, I've realized that my expression can be simplified to cot^2 2x = 1 + 3sec2x, does this make it easier?

Comment: @Carlylepenguin You wrote $\frac{3}{\cos x}$ in the question but $3\sec 2x$ in the comment. Probably a typo in one of them.

Comment: @Greg Martin Good catch, it should've been cos(2x).

Comment: @Learning Mathematics Ok, I think I'm starting to see where you're going, but could you explain a bit further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\cos(2x)^2}{\sin(2x)^2} = 1 +\frac{3}{\cos(2x)}$$ Let $c=\cos(2x)$ to make
$$\frac{c^2}{1-c^2}=1+\frac 3c\implies 2 c^3+3 c^2-c-3=0$$ Using the method for cubic equations, the first thing to notice is that $\Delta=-307$; so there is only one real root.

Using the hyperbolic method for this case, the solution is given by
$$c=-\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}} \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{12
   }{5}\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\right)\right)$$ and then
$$x=\pm \frac 12 \cos^{-1} (c)\sim 0.224024$$ which is not the simplest result.

However, you can *approximate* the result considering that you loof for the zero of function
$$f(x)=\frac{\cos(2x)^2}{\sin(2x)^2} - 1 -\frac{3}{\cos(2x)}$$ which not very convenient because of the vertical asymptotes. Since the solutions cannot be $0$,$\frac \pi 4$, $\frac \pi 4$, consider instead
$$g(x)=\cos(2x)\sin^2(x) f(x)=\cos ^3(2 x)-\sin ^2(2 x) \cos (2 x)-3 \sin ^2(2 x)$$ Since the function is even, we just need to focus on the positive root.

By inspection or graphing, we can notice that the root is close to $0$. So, trying with Taylor series, we have
$$g(x)=1-22 x^2+\frac{130 x^4}{3}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, we face a quadratic in $x^2$ and the smallest root is then given by
$$x=\sqrt{\frac{1}{130} \left(33-\sqrt{699}\right) }\sim 0.224660$$ which is not bad as an approximation.

**Addendum** *(for you personal curiosity)*

We could write $g(x)$ as an infinite series

$$g(x)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{2^{2 n-1} \left(3\ 2^{2 n}+3^{2 n}+1\right) }{(2 n)!}\,x^{2 n}$$ If we truncate it to any order to make it  a truncated Taylor series, we can inverse it and have for example
$$x=t+\frac{65 }{66}t^3+\frac{11923 }{4840}t^5+\frac{108895
   }{13552}t^7+\frac{45684073 }{1533312}t^9+O\left(t^{11}\right)$$ where $t=\sqrt{\frac {1-g(x)}{22}}$. Making $g(x)=0$ as desired, the above would give
$$x=\frac{13209412121291}{12571563755520 \sqrt{22}}\sim 0.224018$$